# Need help calculating percentages for value

Tags: java, percentage

I'm having a little trouble writing a program that I was instructed to do as an assignment.

I'm just curious as to how I calculate a percentage for each value that is entered by the user. I'm having a little trouble trying to find the right way to word this so that it is readable and can be interpreted by Java properly.

My objective is to calculate each individual percentage for the amount of grams in fat, carbs and protein and display it on the screen. I'm not asking for someone to do the assignment for me, I'm just in need of a little guidance.

```
  //local constants

  //local variables
  int carb;           // amount of carbs entered by user
  int fat;            // amount of fat entered by user
  int pro;            // amount of protein entered by user
  int sum;            // sum of three numbers

  //myLib = new Library();

  /********************   Start main method  *****************/

  //Prompt user for amount of carbohydrates
  System.out.print("Please enter the amount of carbohydrates: ");
  carb = Keyboard.readInt();

  //Prompt user for amount of fat
  System.out.print("Please enter the amount of fat: ");
  fat = Keyboard.readInt();

  //Prompt user for amount of protein
  System.out.print("Please enter amount of protein: ");
  pro = Keyboard.readInt();

  //Calculate the sum of the three numbers
  sum = carb + fat + pro;
```

Comment: `carbPercent = (carb/sum)*100` and similarly other percentages. Remember converting either carb (and others in their respective statements) or sum to float or double to get correct output.

Comment: Might want to take a look at this link: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm specifically where it talks about "Confusing Divisions"

Answer (score 1):

As Raman stated, it's relatively easy to calculate percentage now that you have the sum neatly stored in one variable

```
double carbPercent = ((double)carb / sum) * 100
double fatPercent = ((double)fat / sum) * 100
double proteinPercent = ((double)pro / sum) * 100
```

Comment: so you are calculating percentges in `int` ?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava I forgot about the inaccuracies that occur when dividing by `int`s

Comment: @RamanShrivastava Yes, I'm looking to calculate a percentage for each integer.

Comment: @Gonzo - You misunderstood the conversation between me and Michael. Though it is % of integers, but % itself shouldn't be integer. 
You can safely use the answer given by Michael now.